# Merge two or more than two csv in bash or python?

Tags: python, bash, shell, csv, sh

Where if one file1.csv and file2.csv contains different no. of columns such as :
file1:

```
Header : Node_Name,SI ,type,SI ,type,Node_Name,SI  ,type,Node_Name 
Data   : Node_0   ,abc,0   ,xyz,0   ,Node_1   ,rwqe,1   ,Node_2
```

file2:

```
Header : Node_Name,SI,type,Node_Name,SI,type,SI,type,Node_Name,SI,type,SI,type
Data   : Node_0,nbv,0,Node_1,afd,0,mnb,1,Node_2,lm,1,uh,0
```

Merged file:

```
Header : Node_Name,SI,TYPE,SI,TYPE,NODE_NAME,SI,TYPE,SI,TYPE,NODE_NAME,SI,TYPE,SI,TYPE
         Node_0   ,abc,0  ,xyz,0  ,Node_1   ,rwqe,1 ,0 , 0  ,Node_2   ,0 ,0   ,0 ,0
         Node_0   ,nbv,0  , 0 ,0  ,Node_1   ,afd,0  ,mnb,1  ,Node_2   ,lm,1   ,uh,0
```

THANKS IN ADAVNCE

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution in Python is:

```
#read all the files
f1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
f2 = pd.read_csv(file2)

#find all unique column names
col_names = set(list(f1.index) + list(f2.index))

#reset column names, any column doesn't exist in current table will be NaN
f1 = f1.reindex(columns=col_names)
f2 = f2.reindex(columns=col_names)

#Now combine those
combined = pd.concat([f1, f2],  aixs=0)

#deal with missing values
combined = combined.fillna(0)
```

Waiting for a nice bash solution :)

Comment: It looks like 'find all unique column names' is inapplicable here, because files has non-unique columns

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line; do
    echo "$(cut -d, -f-8 <<<"$line"),0,0,$(cut -d, -f9 <<<"$line"),0,0,0,0"
done < file1
while read line; do
    echo "$(cut -d, -f-3 <<<"$line"),0,0,$(cut -d, -f4- <<<"$line")"
done < file2
```

Not overly elegant, but still working.